# 405 for URL: https://www.mutalyzer.nl/position-converter

Tags: java

i am trying to fetch few genomic coordinate using API from the web mutalyzer.nl using the method position converter, but i am getting 405 error. Can you please help?

```
here is my code:-


import java.lang.Object;
import org.apache.commons.*;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;


private long checkVariant() {
        long totalLines = 0;
        File tempInputFile = new File(filePath + "input.tsv");

        File outputFile = new File(filePath + "temp.tsv");
        outputFile.append("Query String" + "\t" + "Response");
        tempInputFile.withReader("UTF-8") { buf ->
            buf.eachLine { line ->
                if (totalLines > 0) {    // skip first line
                    String[] words = line.split("\\t");

                    // fire remote query and check response...
                    //https://www.mutalyzer.nl/position-converter?assembly_name_or_alias=GRCh37&description=NM_024675.3%3Ac.232G%3EA
                    def queryTerm = "description=" + words[1];
                    def query = "assembly_name_or_alias=GRCh37&" + queryTerm;
                    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<code>(.+?)</code>");

                    def urlString = "https://www.mutalyzer.nl/position-converter";
                    def url = new URL(urlString);
                    println urlString;
                    def connection = url.openConnection();
                    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    connection.doOutput = true;

                    def writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.outputStream);
                    println query
                    writer.write(query);
                    println query
                    writer.flush();
                    writer.close();
                    connection.connect();

                    def recaptchaResponse = connection.content.text;
                    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(recaptchaResponse);
                    matcher.find();
                    def answerString = matcher.group(1);
                    //def answer = answerString.replace("Human ", "").replace(" - UCSC Genome Browser v318", "");

                    println "QueryTerm :=" + words[1] + " : Response := " + answerString;

                    outputFile.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") + words[1] + "\t" + answerString);
                }
                totalLines = totalLines + 1;
            }
        }

        return totalLines;      

    }
```

can any one tell me the exact issue?

Answer (score 0):

A http 405 status code means the method is not supported, i.e you're trying to post. From looking at the web pages source its a GET. Try changing

```
  connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

To

```
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

Reference to HTTP 405- http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html

Comment: Can you post your query string and the stack trace?

Comment: i get QueryTerm :=NM_002890.1:c.296C>T : Response := Connect not successful!

Comment: As in the fully constructed URL you are trying to call. Also add the whole stack trace to your original question

Answer (score 0):

What does the API of this website say? Do they support HTTP POST for their APIs.

I called a HTTP GET on following URL (remember that GET has no body in request)

https://www.mutalyzer.nl/position-converter?assembly_name_or_alias=GRCh37&description=NM_003002.3%3Ac.274G%3ET and was able to receive a HTML response from them.

I drilled there site and found they have SOAP Services and REST Services exposed https://www.mutalyzer.nl/webservices where example is given. (What you may be looking is https://www.mutalyzer.nl/soap-api#src.idp856784 submitBatchJob with GET)

Create a SOAP request to invoke soap service or HTTP request to invoke it using REst

https://mutalyzer.nl/json/submitBatchJob?data=Tk1fMDAzMDAyLjM6Yy4yNzRHPlQ=&process=PositionConverter&argument=hg19